# How to configure Redis DB to be Read Only?

Tags: redis

I have a Redis database (no cluster, no replica).
How can i configure it to be read only? (so client can not modify it)
I do not want to set up a replication or cluster.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such configuration for Redis master. Only replicas can be configured as read-only. If you have control over the Redis client library used by your clients, you can change it to expose only read methods to the clients.